# How do I fix span/div issues in Firefox (displays as wanted in IE) and adjust misalignment in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, layout

My personal webpages (at http://ralphemlynmorgan.com) display as planned in IE, but the button labels are slightly offset in Chrome, and the page layout is totally wrong when viewed using Firefox. Any advice for simple changes to fix this (or how to achieve the designed element positioning in a way that works for all browsers) would be appreciated. ;) From html validator error messages I think it has something to do with 'p' not allowed inside span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `<p>` elements in the nav shouldn't have large margins. Change this through `margin: 0`. And yes, `<p>` inside `<span>` is bad. Try to use `<div>` instead.

And change `#centroid` to `position: absolute` to fix the problems in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Misalignment in Firefox and Chrome is due to the absolute positioning of all image and button elements in a page. `<span>` is a inline element. In general we don't include any other elements inside `<span>` element.

Replace all `<span>` elements which has `<p>` element inside with `<div>` element and try removing absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

for navigation better you use ul li
and yes "change #centroid to position: absolute to fix the problems in Firefox."